# Do We Need to Set-Up Multiple Azure Endpoints to Improve Image Load Times Around the World

Tags: azure-cdn

We have configured an Azure endpoint in the Northeastern United States region. Do we now have to manually create additional endpoints around the world in order to improve image load times in countries such as India and Australia, or is the single endpoint that we created in the Northeastern US enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can leverage Azure CDN, which will automatically scale to use servers close to your clients to cache and deliver content from your origin server in northeastern US. You can learn how to get started here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-create-new-endpoint